# UWP can't change Image source in C# code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have been making a UWP Windows Phone app.

Here I added the functionality to change the language.

To do this, I add a `ComboBox` to select languages and an `Image` to display a flag.

When I tried to change the language on `ComboBox` I wanted to change the flag.

My code are below:

```
//index is the selected index of combobox
string strFlag = "ms-appx:///Assets/fl_english.png";
switch(index)
{
    case 0 :
        strFlag = "ms-appx:///Assets/fl_english.png";
        break;
    case 1 :
        strFlag = "ms-appx:///Assets/fl_french.png";
        break;
    case 2 :
        strFlag = "ms-appx:///Assets/fl_germany.png";
        break;
    ....
}

this.img_flag.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strFlag));
```

But when I run the app it exited automatically.

I think the issue was occurred on `this.img_flag.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(flag));`, because app works well without this section.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: This should have worked. While  app exiting does it shows any error or exception ?. If possible add your xaml image section in the question.

Comment: Use a try-catch onto that line of code, to get the precise exception.

Comment: Where did you put this code? Do the images on the given paths actually exist?

Comment: You might want to simply update your UI or even just bind your flag source to a property and raise PropertyChanged event to do it for you whenever you change a picture.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I don't see "flag" declared anywhere.  Did you mean to use the "strFlag" variable you did declare?  E.g.

```
this.img_flag.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(strFlag));
```